# Map Python list element to multiple elements, avoiding nested lists

Tags: python, list

This way I can build a new list by mapping every element in another list:

```
# turn [0,5,10,15] into [1,6,11,16]
[ x+1 for x in range(0,20,5) ]
```

But I want every element to yield two elements in my new lists. How can I do that? Here are my attempts:

```
# turn [0,5,10,16] into [0,1,-5,6,-10,11,-15,16]
# does not work! gives [[0,1],[-5,6],[-10,11],[-15,16]]
[ [-x,x+1] for x in range(0,20,5) ]

# turn [0,5,10,16] into [0,1,-5,6,-10,11,-15,16]
# does not work! gives [(0,1),(-5,6),(-10,11),(-15,16)]
[ (-x,x+1) for x in range(0,20,5) ]
```

Of course I could create the list of lists and then flatten it somehow, but is there a neater way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use two loop:

```
>>> [t for x in range(0,20,5) for t in [-x,x+1] ]
[0, 1, -5, 6, -10, 11, -15, 16]
```

Or if you are dealing with larger data sets you can use `itertools.chain()`

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> 
>>> list(chain.from_iterable([-x,x+1] for x in range(0,20,5)))
[0, 1, -5, 6, -10, 11, -15, 16]
>>>
```

Note that if you just want to iterate over the result you don't have to convert the result to list, because `chain.from_iterable` returns an iterator and is pretty more optimized in terms of memory usage.

Comment: You don't need the list comprehension; drop the brackets to feed a generator to `from_iterable`.

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge, a list comprehension (with one `for`) can not do more than one element at a time. You can either:

- flatten it (`from itertools import chain`)
- Use a function like below and use that as a generator:

  ```
  def myFunc(elements):
      for elem in elements:
          yield -elem
          yield elem + 1
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `functools.reduce` (no need to import it if you are in Python 2.x):

```
from functools import reduce

flat_list = reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, [[-x, x+1] for x in range(0, 20, 5)], [])
```

Or, even better, as @Thrustmaster pointed out:

```
flat_list = sum(([-x, x+1] for x in range(0, 20, 5)), [])
```

Comment: A simple `sum` can do what that `reduce` does.

Comment: @Thrustmaster you are absolutely right! Nice tip :)

Answer (score 0):

Note that the exact notation you are wanting [was proposed but rejected](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/#variations) to add to python:

> Earlier iterations of this PEP allowed unpacking operators inside list, set, and dictionary comprehensions as a flattening operator over iterables of containers:

```
>>> ranges = [range(i) for i in range(5)]
>>> [*item for item in ranges]
[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Using this *rejected* syntax your case would look like:

```
[ *(-x,x+1) for x in range(0,20,5) ]
```

however since list comprehension currently only supports a single element at a time you can simply loop over the additional elements as well:

```
[ item for x in range(0,20,5)
         for item in (-x,x+1) ]
```